# Oracle update table value returned 'single-row sub-query returned more than one row '

Tags: oracle

I wanna add a column named 'Bonus_AMT' on table 'Employee'.
Here's the clause I wrote. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI51i.png)
I ran the above clause, but it didn't work. It returns that 'single-row' sub-query return more than one row. How could I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join table in update clause with table in select clause used in SET. Here is the example.

```
update employees e1 set bonus = (select salary*commission_pct from employees e2 where e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id);
```

You need to make sure that both versions of tables are joined on primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Your select query clause used in set is returning multiple row for the applied date range. So you need to change that select clause so that at a time it will single record and update the same record using joins.